# Weakening captures using Sub::Quote

Tags: perl, moo

I'd like to weaken captured variables in the code generated by [Sub::Quote](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sub::Quote).  For example, here's the non-quoted alternative:

```
use 5.10.0;
use Scalar::Util qw[ weaken ];
{
  my $s = 'foo';
  my $x = sub { say $s };
  weaken( my $y = $x );

  my $bar = sub { &$y };
  &$bar;
  $x = undef;
  &$bar
}
```

and the output:

```
foo
Can't use an undefined value as a subroutine reference [...]
```

And here's my Sub::Quote attempt:

```
use 5.10.0;
use Sub::Quote;
use Scalar::Util qw[ weaken ];
{
  my $s = 'foo';
  my $x = sub { say $s };
  weaken( my $y = $x );

  my $bar = quote_sub( '&$y', { '$y' => \$y } );
  &$bar;
  $x = undef;
  &$bar;
}
```

and the output:

```
foo
foo
```

Obviously the captured `$y` isn't weakened. Is there a way of altering the generated code to weaken captured variables?

The documentation is sparse, and the `Sub::Quote` implementation is complex;  I'm fairly convinced this isn't possible with the current code, but I'd love to be shown to be wrong.

Comment: Does the `weaken` there actually do anything? If it worked, I would've expected `$y` to become `undef` right after `weaken $y`.

Comment: @melpomene, There is a second reference to the CV (as seen using Devel::Peek's `Dump`), though I don't know what it is. /// That said, that means that `$y = undef;` doesn't actually free the sub as the OP expects. The call to `weaken` could be removed without affecting the demo.

Comment: @ikegami I'd assume the second reference is in the optree itself, because the sub is not a closure, so it's probably created during compilation and just kept around forever.

Comment: @melpomene, Oh, *because it's not a closure*, it just returns a reference to the single permanent instance every time you execute `sub { say 'foo' }`. Putting that to the test

Comment: @melpomene, Bingo. Updated the question and the answer.

Comment: I apologize, the code I posted not only did not compile (due to an embarassing cut'n'paste error) but also illustrated confusion on my part about weaken.  Thanks to @ikegami for the corrections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
my $bar = quote_sub( '&$y', { '$y' => \$y } );
```

is roughly the same as

```
my $bar = eval(q{ my $y = $y; sub { &$y } });
```

(It does more, but those bits are irrelevant to this question). As you can see, that creates a new strong reference to the sub<sup>[1]</sup>.

As a workaround, you could add a layer of indirection:

```
my $bar = eval(q{ my $y_ref = \$y; sub { &{ $$y_ref } } });
```

This can be achieved by using:

```
my $bar = quote_sub( '&{$$y_ref}', { '$y_ref' => \\$y } );
```

---

There wouldn't be any problems if the `$y` created by Sub::Quote was an alias for your `$y`. This can be achieved using Data::Alias or an experimental feature introduced in 5.22.

This can be demonstrated using the following:

```
{
  package Sub::Quote;

  my $sub = sub {
    my ($from, $captures, $indent) = @_;
    join(
      '',
      "use feature qw( refaliasing );\n",
      "no warnings qw( experimental::refaliasing );\n",
      map {
        /^([\@\%\$])/
          or croak "capture key should start with \@, \% or \$: $_";
        (' ' x $indent).qq{\\my ${_} = \\${1}{${from}->{${\quotify $_}}};\n};
      } keys %$captures
    )
  };

  no warnings qw( redefine );
  *capture_unroll = $sub;
}


my $bar = quote_sub( '&$y', { '$y' => \$y } );
```

You could talk to the module's maintainer about adding an option that would cause the use of aliasing.

---

1. When you create a copy of a (strong or weak) reference, it's a strong reference.